# How to use variable's value in a Linux path to display contents?

Tags: python

I am stuck at using python variable in Linux path to display contents, any advice/guidance/hints would be very helpful.

Below is my python script:

```
#!/bin/python
import sys 
import os
db = sys.argv[1] 
type = sys.argv[2]
if type == "extract":
    path= 'extractfolder' 
elif type == "transform"
    path = 'transformfolder'
```

I am succesfull so far, now I want to display file based on the path variable. I am stuck here:

```
os.system('hadoop fs -cat /bla/bla/%s/bla/%s/file.txt ' %db %path)

Error: Traceback (most recent call last):   File "./test.py", line 29,in <module>
       os.system('hadoop fs -cat /bla/bla/%s/bla/%s/file.txt' %db %path)

TypeError: not enough arguments for format string
```

Research done:

I have checked `os.system` and also found out `subprocess`, but not very good in subprocess package, couldn't get any hint.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> TypeError:not enough arguments for format string

You need to use tuple/list/etc for format string, eg:

```
os.system('hadoop fs -cat /bla/bla/%s/bla/%s/file.txt ' % (db, path))
```